# Can MiniProfiler profile transactions

Tags: dapper, mvc-mini-profiler

I am able to get Miniprofiler to work with the following dapper statement

```
var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

var conn = new ProfiledDbConnection(new SqlConnection(connString), MiniProfiler.Current);

conn.Open();

var  result = conn.Execute<User>(@"Update Users set firstname...where username=@username",
 new {username},null).Single();

conn.Close();
```

However I would like to be able to track transactions opening, committing, closing or rolling back.  Is that possible to do  with MiniProfiler in a way so that it shows inline with the sql statements.  I see there is a `ProfiledDbTransaction(transaction ,connection);` option but I was not able to make it work

I have wrapped the important parts of the code with Profiler steps similar to but that doesn't read inline with the Sql. If there is a better way I would love to know!

```
 using (profiler.Step("Rollback Transaction"))
      {
          _transaction.Rollback();
      }
```

Comment: interesting; at the moment the answer would be "nothing inbuilt", but it could potentially be added

Comment: Marc thanks for the comment.  It is very helpful as is, but I wanted to check to see if I was just not understanding something.